# Bathroom switch, fan, two lights

Tags: bathroom

I have a bathroom with two lights and a fan. I want to place both lights on a double switch and use the space to add a gfi where the other light switch was. All the wires are black.  How do  I do that?

Comment: What about the fan? Can you include a picture of the switch box? Don't disconnect anything without taking picture first.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please? And yes, how do you want the fan to be controlled?  Also, are there already outlets in the bathroom in question, and is there other stuff on the circuit that powers the lights and fan?

Comment: Sure. How do I do that?